# How to change legend symbol in dxChart

Tags: devexpress, devextreme

i have seen the documentation of DevExpress but i could't find out the way of change the symbol of legend.

can anybody help me out please ?

**JS :**

```
var dataSource = [{
    country: "USA",
    hydro: 59.8,
}, {
    country: "China",
    hydro: 74.2,
}, {
    country: "Russia",
    hydro: 40,
}, {
    country: "Japan",
    hydro: 22.6,
}, {
    country: "India",
    hydro: 19,
}, {
    country: "Germany",
    hydro: 6.1,
}];

var chart = $("#chart").dxChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        argumentField: "country",
        type: 'line'
    },
    margin: {
        bottom: 20
    },
    argumentAxis: {
        valueMarginsEnabled: false,
        discreteAxisDivisionMode: "crossLabels",
        grid: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    series: [
        { valueField: "hydro", name: "Hydro-electric" }
    ],
    legend: {
        verticalAlignment: "bottom",
        horizontalAlignment: "center",
        itemTextPosition: "bottom"
    },
    title: { 
        text: "Energy Consumption in 2004",
    } 
})
```

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body class="dx-viewport">
    <div class="demo-container">
        <div id="chart-demo">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**

[image]

In above example the legend symbol is default "square".
I need to change from "square" to "cross".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the default legend item symbol in dxChart.